I want to send gps location to a telegram bot using nano esp32 over wifi
When using nano esp 32 over wifi to send hard coded location to a telegram bot which i created already, i see and error hitting,
13:01:17.007 -> Sending Hardcoded Location to Telegram

13:01:17.007 -> Sending request to: https://api.telegram.org/bot7054776227:AAELguoi_pNxyf3PVOmDfpJi4miZs5rEh8g/sendMessage?chat_id=7054776227&text=Latitude: 51.5074

13:01:17.007 -> Longitude: -0.1278

13:01:17.499 -> Error on sending GET request: -5

13:01:17.499 -> connection lost

with the code I use nano esp 32 successfully connects to WIFI too. but still notification to telegram bot is not successfull. can someone help me with fixing this please.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
